# QT With C++: How to implement Save As

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to add a save as feature to a simple text editor I'm making with C++ and QT. I'm attempting to close the current tab when you save your file and open a new tab with the same index and has the name of the new file as the tab title. This is my code:

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save As"), "", tr("All Files (*)"));
if (fileName.isEmpty())
        return;
else
{
    QFile file(fileName);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, tr("Unable to open file"),
        file.errorString());
        return;
    }
    QTextStream out (&file);`

    out << ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText();


    QFileInfo FileData(file);

    int currentTab = ui->tabWidget->currentIndex();
    ui->tabWidget->removeTab(currentTab);
    QTextStream InputData(&file);
    ui->tabWidget->insertTab(currentTab, new Form(), FileData.fileName());
    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(currentTab);
    ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(InputData.readAll());

    file.flush();
    file.close();
}
```

When I try to save the new file, it saves the file to the selected location and replaces the current tab with the file name, but it doesn't write the file to the text window. Any help would be great.

Comment: Please tell me:
Where is your plainTextEdit ? on mainwindow or on Form, that you add to tabWidget ?
From your code it seems like the plainTextEdit is on your mainwindow in which your above code lies.
In that case, if there is another plainTextEdit on "Form" then you know that both are different and hence that code will not work.

Comment: @Sumit plainTextEdit is in form, that makes sense why it doesn't work. How would I access the plainTextEdit?

Comment: You should add two public functions to Form class as setter and getter, please see my code posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my demo code and it seems to work:

form.cpp which has a plainTextEdit

```
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"

Form::Form(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Form::~Form()
{
    delete ui;
}

QString Form::GetText()
{
    return ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText();
}

void Form::SetText(QString text)
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->setPlainText(text);
}
```

And the mainwindow.cpp which contains a QTabWidget

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "form.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->tabWidget->insertTab(0, new Form(), "My File");
    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(0);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    int currentIndex = ui->tabWidget->currentIndex();

    //Save the text to a file or a variable...
    QString content = static_cast<Form*>(ui->tabWidget->widget(currentIndex))->GetText();

    ui->tabWidget->removeTab(currentIndex);

    ui->tabWidget->insertTab(currentIndex, new Form(), "Saved File");//new name
    static_cast<Form*>(ui->tabWidget->widget(currentIndex))->SetText(content);
    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(currentIndex);
}
```

It is working for me, please try.
Thank You.

Comment: There pushButton is like "New File" and pushButton_2 is like "Save..." or "Save as..", could not rename in order to reply quickly...